# UISearchBar in right of UINavigationBar in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I created an iPad application in which I would like to have my searchBar to be positioned in the right of a navigation bar.

When I add my search bar in my navigation bar, it is positioned in the middle of the navigationBar. In the middle, instead, I want to show a specific image.

**How can I achieve this?**

Here is my code snippet,

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:150.0 / 255 green:22.0 / 255 blue:22.0 / 255 alpha:0.0]];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo(1).png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:imageView];

self.navigationItem.titleView = sBar;

[titleView release];
```

With the code above, I am able to see only the searchBar (positioned in the middle) in my simulator.

Comment: First, why do you release `titleView`? Maybe you need to release `imageView`. Second, if you add the `sBar`to `self.navigationItem.titleView`, only the bar is visible. If you want to see the image you need to do this: `self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView`.

Comment: For search bar, you could try to see [UIBarButtonItem reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) . Maybe it's possible to pass in an UIView (like the UISearchBar) and put that button in your navigation bar as `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)] autorelease];
searchBar.backgroundImage = [[[UIImage alloc] init] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar] autorelease];
```

You can always change the frame. Always keep in mind that the `backgroundImage` property is only available in iOS 5. You should search for alternative options to get rid of the background for iOS 4.x

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sBar];
```

Answer (score 0):

I screwed around with this and I too couldn't get things to align properly (after adding a couple of buttons next to the search bar).

Until anyone suggests a better solution, you are probably better off just hiding the NavigationBar ([self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]) in that view and replacing it with a UIView with all the UI elements you need.   I think the behavior is more predictable that way.